# what should I do to import cache,ws, jdbc and specs2 % Test

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm upgrading my project from play 2.4.3 to 2.5.0

I have added the sbt plugin for play 2.5.0 in plugin.sbt file like this

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.0")
```

After adding when I compiled the code it throws me an error stating

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ege/Sites/Aeione/greenroom6-services-v3/greenroom6-services-v3/project
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/ege/Sites/Aeione/greenroom6-services-v3/greenroom6-services-v3/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[error] /Users/ege/Sites/Aeione/greenroom6-services-v3/greenroom6-services-v3/project/Common.scala:4: object PlayScala is not a member of package play
[error] import play.PlayScala
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/ege/Sites/Aeione/greenroom6-services-v3/greenroom6-services-v3/project/Common.scala:49: not found: value jdbc
[error]     jdbc,
[error]     ^
[error] /Users/ege/Sites/Aeione/greenroom6-services-v3/greenroom6-services-v3/project/Common.scala:50: not found: value cache
[error]     cache,
[error]     ^
[error] /Users/ege/Sites/Aeione/greenroom6-services-v3/greenroom6-services-v3/project/Common.scala:51: not found: value ws
[error]     ws,
[error]     ^
[error] /Users/ege/Sites/Aeione/greenroom6-services-v3/greenroom6-services-v3/project/Common.scala:52: not found: value specs2
[error]     specs2 % Test,
[error]     ^
[error] 5 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

can anyone help me out to import these dependencies?

Comment: Have you enabled the plugin in your project? `enablePlugins(PlayScala)`

Comment: yes it is enabled

Comment: lazy val common = (project in file("modules/common")).enablePlugins(PlayScala,LauncherJarPlugin)
I have added like this in build.sbt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your import is wrong. According to [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/BuildOverview) it should be:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.sbt._
import Play.autoImport._
import PlayKeys._
```

Comment: Thanks @pme.. I would like to know in documentation where did u find this particular part

Comment: did you check the link in my answer? here is the exact chapter: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/BuildOverview#Using-scala-for-building

Comment: @MANOJ.S.RAMASWAMY in Stackoverflow you thank with upvoting;).